# Swings jLabels doesn't update even though I'm using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I'm writing a little joke-app for a friend of mine and I just can't figure why my labels are not upating and the GUI frozes. I understand that I have to use threads for the background operations in order to keep using the GUI, but it's freezing even before reaching the thread initiation.

Ui class:

```
private class CheckButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        check();
    }
}

public void check() {
    this.jbCheck.setEnabled(false);

    this.rand = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;

            // Offending lines
    this.jlMessage1.setText("");
    this.jlMessage2.setText(this.messages.getString("wait_" + this.rand));
    this.jlMessage2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            // End of the offending lines

    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future<Integer> task = service.submit(new BackgroundJob());

        ping = task.get();
    } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final ExecutionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.jlMessage1.setText("Tienes " + ping + " ms de ping.");
    if (ping <= 125) {
        this.jlMessage2.setText(this.messages.getString("bien_" + this.rand));
        this.jlMessage2.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (ping > 126 && ping <= 200) {
        this.jlMessage2.setText(this.messages.getString("medio_" + this.rand));
        this.jlMessage2.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    } else {
        this.jlMessage2.setText(this.messages.getString("mal_" + this.rand));
        this.jlMessage2.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }

    service.shutdownNow();
    this.jbCheck.setEnabled(true);
}
```

And this is the background job:

```
public class BackgroundJob implements Callable<Integer> {

private int ping;

@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "ping " + Constants.IP + " | find \"Media\"");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

    try {
        Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = br.readLine().trim();
        ping = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[8].split("ms")[0]);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ping;
}
```

}

I have no clue why it's not changing the labels before the call to `Future<Integer> task = service.submit(new BackgroundJob());`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is not changing the labels, because you are within the "main" thread, responsible for repainting the GUI. You call

```
ExecutorService service = null;
try {
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    Future<Integer> task = service.submit(new BackgroundJob());

    ping = task.get();
```

to spawn a thread asynchronously. But the call `task.get();` is again a blocking operation. So you spawn the background thread, but wait blocking for its result.

Comment: After the task has been completed, the execution enter the if and the gui changes. My problem is before reaching the task call. Those labels should be changing, right?. Also, the button is not being disabled (I forgot to mention that).

Comment: No. How should they? There is a "main" thread, which is responsible for the repainting of the GUI and for handling (for example) buttons clicks. You block the thread. The thread cannot repaint the GUI.

Comment: I fail to understand your point. If I run the code using the debugger, the offending lines are being called just fine.

Comment: That is correct. The labels are being modified. But the only thread that could repaint the actual window is being blocked. Try and remove `ping = task.get();` (and replace it with a dummy value). The labels and everything contain the correct values in the GUI now, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that removing that line makes the labels work... I'm going to think about this a little bit more, I just realized something. :)

Comment: You might also want to take a look into SwingUtilities and the invokeNow/invokeLater methods to update the GUI from another thread, if you think about moving the upper code into the thread.